# Prove that the limit of the following sequence $\frac{n^3 + 2}{n^2 + 3}$ diverges to $+ \infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

The question is:

Prove that the  limit of the following sequence $\frac{n^3 + 2}{n^2 + 3}$ diverges to $+ \infty$.

My choice to $N$ was the floor of $M/2$ plus 1, am I right?

where I found a sequence larger than the given sequence which is $2n$ and where  in my definition I have the assumption that $n \geq N$.

Comment: You could just divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$ and you are done since you get $(n+O(1/n))/(1+O(1/n))$

Comment: I want a proof using the sequence limit definition @MarcoBellocchi

Comment: @Idonotknow "I want" is never really nice...

Comment: @amsmath sorry the question wants :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to show that $f(n) \geq M$ for all $n \geq N$.

What you have doesn’t work. For example taking $M=3$ gives $N=2$. But $f(2)=\frac{10}{7} < 3$.

Comment: I think the right value is N = floor 2M + 1 right?

Comment: Yes, that’s good. Notice that for $n \geq N=\text{floor}(2M)+1 \geq (2M-1)+1=2M$ we have $n \geq 2M$. Multiplying $n \geq 2M$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ gives $\frac{1}{2}n \geq M$. Or $f(n)>\frac{1}{2} n \geq M$, if you implement @Nosrati’s answer. This shows $f(n) >M$ for $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{n^3 + 2}{n^2 + 3}>\frac{n^3 }{n^2 + n^2}=\dfrac12n>N$$
so it is sufficient to let $M=2N$.

Comment: why you found a sequence less than and not greater than?

Comment: @Idonotknow It is because you wish to show that the sequence diverges to infinity.

Comment: Strange thing you got the same value of $N$ as me even though I took the greater sequence..... could you explain this for me please?